# Evaluation of trignometric limit

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I want to find the following limit without L'Hospital.

$ \lim_{x \to \frac{3π}{4}} \frac{1+(\tan x)^{\frac13}}{1-2(\cos x)^2}$

Maybe I should try to get rid of the radical.

Comment: Did you try conjugating the denominator?

Comment: How would that help?

Comment: Is Taylor's series considered LHR?

Comment: I am ok with a solution using Taylor's series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the OP suggested openness to asymptotic analysis, we proceed accordingly.

First, we note the expansion of the numerator is given by

$$\begin{align}
1+\tan^{1/3} x&=1+\left(-1+2(x-3\pi/4)+O(x-3\pi/4)^2\right)^{1/3}\\\\
&=\frac23 (x-3\pi/4)+O(x-3\pi/4)^2 \tag 1
\end{align}$$

whereas the expansion of the denominator is given by
and

$$\begin{align}
1-2\cos^2x&=-\cos 2x\\\\
&=-2(x-3\pi/4)+O(x-3\pi/4)^3 \tag 2
\end{align}$$

Thus, putting $(1)$ and $(2)$ together yields

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1+\tan^{1/3} x}{1-2\cos^2x}&=\frac{\frac23 (x-3\pi/4)+O(x-3\pi/4)^2}{-2(x-3\pi/4)+O(x-3\pi/4)^3}\\\\
&=-\frac13+O(x-3\pi/4)\\\\
&\to -\frac13\,\,\text{as}\,\,x\to 3\pi/4
\end{align}$$

Therefore, we have that the limit of interest is

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{x\to 3\pi/4}\frac{1+\tan^{1/3} x}{1-2\cos^2x}=-\frac13}$$

---

**NOTES:**

To arrive at $(1)$, we first note that for $f(x)=\tan x$, $f'(x)=\sec^2 x$ and $f''(x)=2\sec^2 x\tan x$.

Therefore, $f(3\pi/4)=-1$ and $f'(3\pi/4)=\frac12$ so that

$$\tan x=-1+2(x-3\pi/4)+O(x-3\pi/4)^2$$

Then, using the expansion for $(-1+x)^{1/3}=-1+\frac13x+O(x^2)$, we see that

$$\begin{align}
\tan^{1/3} x&= \left(-1+2(x-3\pi/4)+O(x-3\pi/4)^2\right)^{1/3}\\\\
&=-1+\frac23(x-3\pi/4)+O(x-3\pi/4)^2
\end{align}$$

---

To arrive at $(2)$, we first note the trigonometric identity $\cos 2x=2\cos^2-1$.

Then, for $g(x)=1-2\cos^2 x=-\cos 2x$, we have $g'(x)=2\sin 2x$, $g''(x)=4\cos 2x$, and $g'''(x)=-8 \sin 2x$.

Therefore, $g(3\pi/4)=0$ and $g'(3\pi/4)=-2$, and $g''(3\pi/4)=0$ so that

$$-\cos 2x=-2(x-3\pi/4)+O(x-3\pi/4)^3$$

Comment: I am sorry. I thought you were talking about the series expansion of tan x or cos x. I am unaware of asymptotic analysis. But can you give me some idea about it as the solution is pretty short.

Comment: @Irrational3.14 Those are indeed the truncated series expansions.  Does that help?

Comment: How is this truncation carried out? I can't relate it with the expansion of tan x I know of.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I had one last doubt. For the approximate expansion of (1+x)^n we have a condition |x|<1. Any such restrictions on (-1+x)^n ?

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.  And good observation.  Yes, the same applies here.  Inasmuch as we are letting $x$ in that expansion go to zero (remember that that "$x$" is actually our $x-3\pi/4$), the expansion is valid.

Answer (score 3):

We will use the fact that $(a^3+b^3)=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$. This will help us rationalize the numerator. With $a=1$and $b=(\tan x)^{1/3}$ we can write
\begin{align*}
\frac{1+(\tan x)^{1/3}}{1-2\cos^2x}& = \frac{1+(\tan x)^{1/3}}{1-2\cos^2x} \cdot \left[\color{blue}{\frac{1-(\tan x)^{1/3}+(\tan x)^{2/3}}{1-(\tan x)^{1/3}+(\tan x)^{2/3}}}\right]\\
& = \frac{1+\tan x}{1-2\cos^2x}\cdot \left[\frac{1}{1-(\tan x)^{1/3}+(\tan x)^{2/3}}\right]
\end{align*}
Now use the following identity:
$$\cos 2x=2 \cos^2 x -1 =\frac{1-\tan^2x}{1+\tan^2x},$$
to get
\begin{align*}
\frac{1+(\tan x)^{1/3}}{1-2\cos^2x}&= \frac{1+\tan^2 x}{\tan x-1}\cdot \left[\frac{1}{1-(\tan x)^{1/3}+(\tan x)^{2/3}}\right]
\end{align*}
Now use the fact that $x \to 3\pi/4$ to get the limit as $-1/3$.

Answer (score 1):

let us make a change of variable $x = 3\pi/4 + h.$ then we have 
$$\begin{align}\tan(x) &= \tan(3\pi/4 + h) = \frac{-1 + \tan h}{1 + \tan h} \\
&= (\sin h - \cos h)(\sin h + \cos h \cdots)^{-1} \\
&=(-1 + h \cdots)(1+h +\cdots)^{-1} \\
&=(-1 + h \cdots)(1-h +\cdots) \\
&=-1+2h+\cdots\\
\tan^{1/3} x &=-1 + \frac23 h+\cdots\\
1+\tan^{1/3} x &= \frac23 h+\cdots \tag 1\\
\sqrt 2\cos x &= \sqrt 2\cos(3\pi/4+h)= -\cos h - \sin h\\
&=-1 - h + h^2/2+\cdots\\
2\cos^2 x &=  1+2h+\cdots\\
1-2\cos^2 x &= -2h+\cdots \tag 2
\end{align}$$

from $(1)$ and $(2),$  $$\lim_{x \to 3\pi/4} \frac{1+\tan^{1/3} x}{1-2\cos^2 x }=\frac{2h/3+\cdots}{-2h + \cdots} = -\frac 13. $$

Comment: Hey, well done.  Same as mine with $h\to x-3\pi/4$ ... ;-))

Comment: @Dr.MV, thanks. yes. i like to keep the small parameter separate.

Comment: Yes.  I usually do so also.  Here, I thought it might be instructive for some readers to see the "raw" development.